# Binding inside binding with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have json file with key:value, for example "TRANS_NAME": "Some name".
In controller:

```
$scope.translate = TranslateData.get().data; //gets that json with key : value
```

In template/html

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{contacts.keyTranslationName}}</label>
</div>
```

I need to get contacts.keyTranslationName from $scope.translate as a key, is it possible to do something like this:

{{ translate.{{contacts.keyTranslationName}} }}

Comment: {{translate[contacts.keyTranslationName]}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may helps you

```
{{ translate[contacts.keyTranslationName] }}
```

Comment: glad to help you :) cheerz

Answer (score 0):

```
{{translate[contacts.keyTranslationName]}}
```